# Python flood fill not returning

Tags: python, recursion, flood-fill

I'm currently developing a flood fill code to fill polygons in a software renderer I made for my Computer Graphics class. Here's the code below of my recursion, I based it on an algorithm from geeksforgeeks.

```
def flood(self, x, y, colorOld, colorNew):
    if (x < 0 or x >= self.width or y < 0 or y >= self.height):
        print("height/width not in range")
        return
    if (self.framebuffer[x][y] != colorOld):
        print("color is old")
        return

    print(str(x) + ", " + str(y))

    self.point(x, y, colorNew)

    self.flood(x+1, y, colorOld, colorNew)
    self.flood(x-1, y, colorOld, colorNew)
    self.flood(x, y+1, colorOld, colorNew)
    self.flood(x, y-1, colorOld, colorNew)
    return

def floodFill(self, x, y, colorN):
    colorO = self.framebuffer[x][y]
    self.flood(x, y, colorO, colorN)
```

However, it gets stuck when it reaches the end of the width, it's not returning even though it reaches one of the flags.

If I need to provide my whole renderer, just tell me.

Comment: This code looks correct, but we don't have the implementation of `self.point(x, y, colorNew)`. Can you check that this function indeed changes the color? (I.e. make sure it is equivalent to `self.framebuffer[x][y] = colorNew`)

Comment: @BarakItkin you are right, my point function colors y first and then x, so I had to change my flood as well. Thank you for noticing this mistake.

Comment: This is an infinite recursion if you try to flood a point with the color it already has, and there's at least one adjacent pixel with the same color - it will go back and forth between those two pixels forever.